# Terminating plugin 'CredentialProvider.Microsoft' due to an unrecoverable fault

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, credentials, credential-manager

Trying to push nuget to Azure DevOps, hitting authentication error below. Tried deleting all generic credentials, reinstalling the credential manager...

```
dotnet nuget push --source "XXX" --api-key az "XXXX.nupkg"
Terminating plugin 'CredentialProvider.Microsoft' due to an unrecoverable fault:  NuGet.Protocol.Plugins.ProtocolException: A plugin protocol exception occurred.
 ---> NuGet.Protocol.Plugins.ProtocolException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
   at NuGet.Protocol.Plugins.OutboundRequestContext`1.HandleFault(Message fault)
   at NuGet.Protocol.Plugins.MessageDispatcher.OnMessageReceived(Object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
   at NuGet.Protocol.Plugins.Connection.OnMessageReceived(Object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
   at NuGet.Protocol.Plugins.Receiver.FireMessageReceivedEvent(Message message)
   at NuGet.Protocol.Plugins.StandardOutputReceiver.OnLineRead(Object sender, LineReadEventArgs e)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
error: The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of -0.001 seconds elapsing.
error:   A task was canceled.
error:   Pushing took too long. You can change the default timeout of 300 seconds by using the --timeout <seconds> option with the push command.
```